# Laravel filter relation's data by other relations data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eager-loading

I am trying to filter my **tickets.tips.drawDates** relation's data by other relation's column (**results.draw_date**) in an eager-loading query. Does anybody have any advice on how to accomplish that?

```
$products = Product::with([
        'results' => function ($query) use ($drawDates) {
            return $query->whereBetween('draw_date', $drawDates);
        },
        'tickets' => function ($query) use ($drawDateFrom) {
            return $query->whereDate('valid_until', '>=', $drawDateFrom)->where('status', 'pending');
        },
        'tickets.tips',
        'tickets.tips.drawDates' => function($query) {
            return $query->whereNull('status')->whereDate('draw_date', 'HERE SHOULD BE draw_date COLUMN FROM results RELATION');
        },
        'prizes'
    ])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with the `whereColumn()` function, it is used to verify that two columns are equal, something like that:

```
return $query->whereNull('status')->whereColumn('draw_date', 'results.draw_date');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried this, but no luck. The system tries to read 'results.draw_date' as a raw column name, in that case, I am getting an error: Column not found.

Comment: You have to adjust the code I posted to follow the naming of your table.field. I can't know your database structure, mine was only an example based on the info you posted.